# ssh batch script windows : unable to send my commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh

I wrote a little script, to automate some actions on a server

```
@echo off
SET /P host= enter host adress : 
@echo off
plink.exe -ssh user@%host% -P 22 -pw password -batch -m "C:\path\to\my_commands.txt"
pause
```

I can connect with this script, no problem with that. But when I run it, it's not sending what I wrote in my_commands.txt

I've tried to wrote my commands like this :
`plink.exe -ssh user@%host% -P 22 -pw password -batch mkdir /my/path`

I've tried with or without quotes for the path to my_commands.txt

In both ways, cmd keep telling "bash : mkdir : command not found"

It look like cmd is trying to take the "my_commands.txt" as parameter.

Comment: Make sure your host is Linux!

Comment: I'm sure. It's a CentOS 7 :)

Comment: Make sure mkdir command exist in your bash in your linux